# Is a new docker instance/image created everytime a web request arrives?

Tags: python, docker, nginx, flask, nginx-reverse-proxy

So, I am really confused on how nginx works with docker.
Suppose I have a python flask container website hosted on two servers and I am using nginx to load balance from a third server, Say bastion.
So, everytime I visit the website, will a new docker -flask-instance/image be created to serve the client? Or all are served from the one flask image?
If yes, where can I find the new instances names which are created.

Comment: There will be as many flask instances as **you** start.

Answer (score 1):

First of you seem to be confused about the concept of images in docker. For your flask application there should only be 1 image, and there can be any number of containers which are running instances of this image.

you can see all running instances (containers) with  `docker ps`.

And no generally speaking, there will not be a new container for every request.